# What Certification(s) to look for in Hard Drive destruction?

Tags: certification, disposal

Many vendors exist to pick up old (enterprise) Hardware for recycling and offer services including sanitization and destruction (shredding).

The concern is that media could potentially still contain sensitive information (through data remanence or simply human error forgetting to sanitize the media before disposal).

Is there any certifications (e.g. ISO) that a vendor should possess to be entrusted with old storage media (especially hard drives and SSDs)?

Comment: This will depend heavily on your location and/or the location of the contractor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look for a company that uses DoD 5220-22.M standards for data destruction : http://www.dss.mil/documents/odaa/nispom2006-5220.pdf

I use a company that says they meet that standard.